# Transform:Translate Not Working

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to make a button animation but `transform:translateY` doesn't appear to be working for me.

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding:0;
 
}
.btn {
 height: 42px;
 width: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: none;
 background-color: #E6E6FF;
 box-shadow: 0 8px #ccccff;
}
.btn:focus {
 outline:0;
 
}
.btn:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 4px #ccccff;
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
.btn:active {
 box-shadow:none;
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  <button class="btn"></button>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I m trying to make the button flush with the other once pressed. The box shadows disappears, but the button isn't moved another 4 pixels down by `transform: translateY(4px);` Not sure why this is happening, your thoughts would be great.

Comment: **When** do you expect the button to be moved another 4 pixels down? I suspect `:active` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: When I click it. It already removes the shadows (which I want) but It doesn't move down the 4px to make it look like a natural press.

Comment: I believe it is because you are saying to move it down 4px from its original position. If you try 8px on the :active field does that achieve what you want?

Comment: Does this do what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/zwapyv0s/

Comment: Yeah, thanks guys, I was just didn't realise the translate position was relative to its original position. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.btn:active {
box-shadow:none;
transform: translateY(8px);
```

}

Comment: Why? What does this do? Explain the answer - code only answers are not very helpful.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I just didn't know that it translates it from the original position. Thanks!